# One source for webpage between cellphone, tablet and PC

Tags: html, css

I am attempting creating [link1](http://www.stockton.co.za/lcars) so that it would work on my Nexus 5 cellphone, my Lenovo 7" tablet as well as a PC.

Currently works fine on the cellphone and PC but not so much on the tablet.
If you wish to test go to the website I mentioned and click on the right hand side of the image which should take you to [link2](http://devacs.za.net/lcars/main.html) and if you are using a tablet you will see that the buttons among other things is/are misplaced.

The piece of html in `main.html` that I think is wrong is:

Please tell me how I fix this as I suspect that the `tablet.css` is not getting loaded.

```
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
<link href="css/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and ((min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 600px))" />
<link href="css/index.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 600px)" />
```

Comment: Can you indent the block of HTML by 4 spaces, so it becomes visible?

Comment: I see that some of the stylesheets overlap in functionality, by the way. On a device exactly 600px wide, which stylesheet is supposed to be used?

Comment: Try remove outer `()` from `((min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 600px))`